# Differential Equation for cooling speed

Tags: calculus, ordinary-differential-equations

Suppose that a cup of boiling hot coﬀee (ie its temperature is $100^oC$) is left in a $20^oC$
room and sits until it has cooled to $60^oC$. The cup of coﬀee is then taken outside where
the temperature is $5^oC$. After 15 minutes, the coﬀee is now $25^oC$. How long has the
coﬀee been cooling in total?

Normally I would have some sort of idea where to start, but with this I have absolutely no idea how. Can someone give me some guidance on this?

Thanks.

Comment: Well it seems you just need to use Newton's Law of Cooling to find the time it takes to cool from 100 to 60 degrees.

Answer (score 1):

**Hint**

Split the problem in two parts and use Newton'law of cooling which write $$T(t)=T_a+c e^{-kt}$$ For $t=0$, you have $T_{ini}=T_a+c$ which means that $c=T_{ini}-T_a$ and then $$T(t)=T_a+(T_{ini}-T_a) e^{-kt}$$ For the first situation, you are given $T_{ini}=100$ and $T_a=20$ and the coffee cools until its temperature reaches $T=60$; if you replace the numbers, the coffee was kept in the room for a time $t_1$ such that $e^{kt_1}=\frac{1}{2}$.

Now, for the second situation, you are given $T_{ini}=60$ and $T_a=5$ and it takes $15$ minutes in order $T=25$. So, $$25=60+(5-60)e^{-15k}$$ then $$k=\frac{1}{15} \log \left(\frac{11}{7}\right)$$ Back to the first situation, we then have $$e^{kt_1}=\frac{1}{2}$$ Replacing $k$ by the above value then gives $$t_1=\frac{15 \log (2)}{\log \left(\frac{11}{7}\right)} \simeq 23$$

So the coffee spent $23$ minutes indoors and $15$ minutes outdoors

Answer (score 0):

Let me add some more thoughts, appart from the excellent answer of Leibovici.

The heat equation for the heating/cooling of a body when convenction is present is given by:

$$ \rho c_p \partial_t T = \nabla \cdot k \nabla T  + h ( T - T_\infty), $$ where $\rho$ is the mass of the body per unit volume (density), $c_p$ its specific heat, $k$ is the coefficient of thermal conductivity, $h$ is a convective heat transfer coefficient and $T_\infty$ is the sourrounding temperature. If we make the assumption that the heat transfer is independent of the form of the object (i.e., the heat by conduction is far less important than the heat by convection), then we can set the diffusive term to zero, yielding:

$$ \rho c_p \frac{\mathrm{d}T}{\mathrm{d}t} = h (T - T_\infty). \tag{1}$$ This is the well known Newton's law for cooling. Since we don't know $h$, and, furthermore, we don't know *a priori* the sign of $(T-T_\infty$), we might come up with negative values of $h$ when solving the problem. This it's completly wrong from a phyisical point of view but it make sense if we consider that when $h<0$, it just means that the sign of the term $T-T_\infty$ is the opposite.

On the other hand, you have two situations to be analyzed:

- *Situation 1*: $T_0 = 100$, $T_\infty$, $T_F = 60$ and $t_F = 15$; temperatures in degrees Celsius and time in $\mathrm{min}$.
- *Situation 2*: $T'_0 = T_F = 60$, $T'_\infty = 5$, $T'_F = 25$ and $t'_F = t_F + t'$, where $t'$ is the outdoors cooling time.

Integrate the equation $(1)$ according to the two situations to have:

$$\begin{align} 
& \log \frac{T_F - T_\infty}{T_0 - T_\infty} = \alpha \,  t_F, \\
& \log \frac{T'_F - T'_\infty}{T'_0 - T'_\infty} = \alpha  \, (t_F + t' - t_F).
\end{align}$$ Note that this system of equations is quite straightforward to solve for your unknowns $\alpha = h/\rho c_p$ and $t'$ (it is convenient to convert $t_F$ from minutes to seconds) since everything else is given.

I hope this helps.

Cheers!

**Edit**: in this context, $T_0$ means the temperature at time $t_0$ and $T_F$ means the temperature at time $t_F$ while $T'_0 = T_F$ and $T'_F$ means the temperature at time $t = t_F + t' = t'_F$.